# Ceiling fan does not change speed with wall controller but does change speed with pull chain

Tags: electrical, switch, ceiling-fan

Ceiling fan only blows on high when using wall switch(fan control),. but it does change speeds when using pull chain. I replaced fan control but problem still exists.

It is a 3 speed knob type fan lutron fan control there is a 14/3(red) for hot and 14/2 (black ) for switch leg replaced with new one and same problem fan only blows on high when I turn it on but does change speed with pull chain. I have it set to high with pull chain to control with wall switch

Comment: Please revise to tell us something about the wiring and switch hardware. We don't have much to go on here.

Comment: Obviously the wall controller is not set up to control the fan.

Comment: I agree with hot licks, ceiling fans usually use different windings for different speeds if the fan is not left in the high speed setting the controller won’t be able to do much if anything.

Comment: Fan pull chain setting is on high